# Spamassassin with one rule and multiple files

Tags: spamassasin

I was given a task to write a Java program that gets user input as text from a GUI screen, create a Spamassassin rule according to that rule and test the rule against a set of `.eml` files.

Therefore I think a should call spamassassin process with some arguments and get the processes return value. Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

When you call `spamassassin` with `-h` you get the help:

```
-e, --exit-code                   Exit with a non-zero exit code if the
                                  tested message was spam
```

and you can set the configuration directory using `-C`, so you don't have to clutter the normal configuration when adding your "rules"

You just call spamassassin with these options and some email to test against as argument from your program.